# The page broke after Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have implemented multi level filter for my portfolio with live update using Ajax, my portfolio is a expandable div which will run using this jQuery code

```
$(function() {
    Grid.init();
});
```

Relevant code

```
var Grid = (function() {

        // list of items
    var $grid = $( '#og-grid' ),
        // the items
        $items = $grid.children( 'li' ),
        // current expanded item's index
        current = -1,
        // position (top) of the expanded item
        // used to know if the preview will expand in a different row
        previewPos = -1,
        // extra amount of pixels to scroll the window
        scrollExtra = 0,
        // extra margin when expanded (between preview overlay and the next items)
        marginExpanded = 10,
        $window = $( window ), winsize,
        $body = $( 'html, body' ),
        // transitionend events
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
            'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition' : 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        // support for csstransitions
        support = Modernizr.csstransitions,
        // default settings
        settings = {
            minHeight : 350,
            speed : 350,
            easing : 'ease'
        };

    function init( config ) {

        // the settings..
        settings = $.extend( true, {}, settings, config );

        // preload all images
        $grid.imagesLoaded( function() {

            // save item´s size and offset
            saveItemInfo( true );
            // get window´s size
            getWinSize();
            // initialize some events
            initEvents();

        } );

    }
```

Ajax Call

```
// AJAX update
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch ($_GET['action']) {
        case 'update':
            require __DIR__ . '/portfolio--results.php';
            break;
    }

    die( 0 );
}



function update_results() {
    var $form = $(this).parents("form");

    var data = $form.serializeArray();
        data.push({
            name:  "action",
            value: "update"
        });

    $.ajax({
        type    : "GET",
        data    : data,
        success : function(response) {
            $(".search-results").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Event Listeners

```
$(document).on("click", "menu:not(:last-child) input", update_results);
    $(document).on("click", "menu:not(:first-child) input", update_results);
```

page working well till i load data using Ajax and the portfolio functionality will broke.
I know there is a method to delegate the jQuery code to fix the Ajax issue, but i'm not very familiar with jQuery, is anybody able to help me out with this issue?

I copy and pasted the code to the page that Ajax is loading that ad it works just once and will broke after selecting more filters.

Comment: I don't see an ajax call.  I see some PHP.

Comment: @Smeegs just update it